# Change angular-cli test folder to another directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, angular5

I would like to know if it's possible change the path `test` to another folder, for example:

```
test/jest/**/*.spec.ts
test/karma/**/*.spec.ts
```

This is what I'm trying, but without success

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"test": {
  "karma": {
    "config": "./karma.conf.js"
  },
  "codeCoverage": {
    "exclude": [
      "**/test/jest/*.spec.ts"
    ]
  }
},
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
exclude: [
  "**/test/jest/*.spec.ts"
]
```

**src/test.ts**

```
const context = require.context('./test/karma/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

**src/tsconfig.spec.json**

```
"exclude": [
  "**/test/jest/*.spec.ts"
]
```

When I run `npm test`, the karma tests doesn't work (which was working) and it still reading `/test/jest/`

```
ERROR in src/test/jest/services/cart.spec.ts(5,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'test'.

[karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
[launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
[launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
[launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
```

I've already try reinstall my modules, but it still the same.

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ rm -f package-lock.json
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install
```

**package.json**

```
"@angular": "^5.2.9"
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.3"
"karma": "~2.0.0"
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

The follow changes, did work.

**karma.conf.js**

```
exclude: [
  "**/test/jest/**/*.spec.ts"
]
```

**tsconfig.spec.json**

```
"exclude": [
  "**/test/jest/*"
]
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"test": {
  "karma": {
    "config": "./karma.conf.js"
  },
  "codeCoverage": {
    "exclude": [
      "**/test/jest/**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
  }
},
```